# How to check who run pipeline in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure-synapse

**I need to find who running this pipeline and I would like to know who launched a pipeline.**

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in below image you can find out who run pipeline.

**Go to** `Monitor -> Pipeline runs`

Here you will see `Triggered by`

[image]

You can also refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/monitoring/how-to-monitor-pipeline-runs#access-pipeline-runs-list) for more information.